# Formatting Currency(U.S) not working with data from Sql Server Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a code that binds the data from the database to textboxes. The problem is I want to make one of the textboxes **Payment** use a dollar sign.

I tried formatting it as shown in the code below but only the first record gets formatted, the rest do not. When I click the next button, the dollar sign disappeared.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
bs = New BindingSource(ds, ds.Tables(0).TableName)
Me.txtPayment.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Payment")
Me.txtPayment.Text = Format(CType(txtPayment.Text, Decimal), ("c"))
```

I have tried everything else I know, *FormatCurrency* but no luck.

Payment is the name of the column in the database, the data type in SQL Server is 
*Small Money*.

I would really appreciate any ideas!

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the above code did not work is because the code only fired once when the form load.

So the solution is to either change the code to this:

```
Me.txtPayment.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Payment", True,
DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, 0, "c")
```

Or to place the below section of the code in the text change event, like this:

```
Private Sub txtPayment_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPayment.TextChanged
      Me.txtPayment.Text = Format(CType(txtPayment.Text, Decimal), ("c"))
End Sub
```

And that's it!